# video extending past the bounds of a VideoView in Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-videoview

I'm currently working on some legacy code that previously functioned as a popup in an application that showed an image alongside some text. I am  altering the layout, changing it from an ImageView to a VideoView, in order to make it show videos. I have set the video view to span only a certain portion of the screen, but the video is not staying within those bounds. It starts in the upper left corner of those bounds as it is supposed to, but spans out passed it in all other directions and over the bottom and right edges of the screen.

[Here is the layout view from Android Studio, The red line shows how the video is showing. It should stay (scale?) within the square video view where the top left corner of the video begins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4zufo.png)

The legacy code was using an ImageView next to another ImageView with overlayed text in order to make up the popup. The parent of these elements is a PercentRelativeLayout. I have tried adding another Relative Layout that is the total size of the popop, and then adding the video and image view inside of that (structure: Percent (full screen) -> Percent (popup size) -> video (left half of parent) & image (right half of parent)). The video is still extending passed the bounds.
I have also tried using Constraint Layouts instead of Percent layouts but it had no effect.
I ran the same code on a different device that is using the same OS but faster hardware and the code is working as expected.
I am not altering the video view within the code except for setting the video source.

```
<android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    tools:context="com.my.package.questionnaire.fragments.InterestQuestionFragment">

    <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        app:layout_aspectRatio="177%"
        app:layout_widthPercent="100%">

        <android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout
            android:background="#000000"
            app:layout_heightPercent="64%"
            app:layout_marginStartPercent="13%"
            app:layout_marginTopPercent="18%"
            app:layout_widthPercent="74%">

            <ImageView
                android:src="@drawable/info_popup_background"
                app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
                app:layout_marginStartPercent="50%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />

            <VideoView
                android:id="@+id/info_popup_accessory_video_view"
                app:layout_heightPercent="100%"
                app:layout_widthPercent="50%" />

        </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

    </android.support.percent.PercentRelativeLayout>

</android.support.percent.PercentFrameLayout>
```

Expected results are for the video to stay inside the bounds of the VideoView. The video is not large and should already be relatively the same size as the VideoView that I am creating. It seems to be getting stretched, while it should not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in case anybody else runs into this issue, I will lay out the solution that I found.
As it turns out, this issue was present on Android 4.4.2 and not in 4.4.4. In order to find a fix for this I turned to the scalableVideoView library which is essentially just a light wrapper for mediaPlayer that changes its textureView via video listeners and can be found at 
https://github.com/yqritc/Android-ScalableVideoView.

This uses a MediaPlayer inside of a textureView. 
This library fixed the video scaling issue but introduced a different documented bug that freezes the application when releasing the mediaplayer. 
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36905656

In order to remedy that, I dove into the library and stripped out the MediaPlayer and all related Listeners and methods, and implemented Google's ExoPlayer. The Library is totally different now, so if anybody is interested, I can supply it.

Now, everything is working as expected, no scaling or freezing issues.

If anybody wants to see code for this, just let me know and I can elaborate!